# Splitting a string on an "undefined" variable

Tags: c#, .net

I have a piece of text that is in multiple formats, and I want to try and create a method that encompasses all of them. I know where I can split these lines, however, I am uncertain of how to define this.

An example of the text:

> .0 index .0.label unicode "Area" .0.value unicode "6WAY DB" .1 index .1.label unicode "SubStation" .1.value unicode "E782DB257" .2 (etc...)

I want to split these lines on the ".0", ".1", etc, so that my list will look like:

> .0 index
>  
>   .0.label unicode "Area"
>  
>   .0.value unicode "6WAY DB"
>   .1 index
>  
>   .1.label unicode "SubStation"

This will make the data easier to manipulate. However, since the value changes depending on the line, I can't simply sate the value as a regular string. Instead, I was thinking of stating is more like

```
string Split = "." + n.IsInt();
```

Or something similar. However, I can't find anything that has worked yet.

Comment: What about using regular expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understand you, you can do the following with regex replace

```
var input = ".0 index .0.label unicode \"Area\" .0.value unicode \"6WAY DB\" .1 index .1.label unicode \"SubStation\" .1.value unicode \"E782DB257\" .2 (etc...)";

var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\.\d", $"{Environment.NewLine}$&");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

or to actually split

```
var lines = result.Split(new[]{Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.None);

foreach (var line in lines)
   Console.WriteLine(line);
```

**Output**

```
.0 index
.0.label unicode "Area"
.0.value unicode "6WAY DB"
.1 index
.1.label unicode "SubStation"
.1.value unicode "E782DB257"
.2 (etc...)
```

**Explanation**

- `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)

  - `\d` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)

`$&` replaces with the original match

Comment: I'm not well-versed in regular expressions so I may be missing something obvious, but if `{1}` is a "meaningless quantifier," then why include it?

Comment: @TheGeneral this is great! Thanks very much! I did run into one error though - if the line has an other instance of `@"\.\d"`, it will split the line there as well, (Eg. ".1.value Unicode "**.6**WAY DB"). So I instead specified using this regex instead: `@"(\.\d index)|(\.\d\.label)|(\.\d\.value)"`

Comment: @Ben that looks like the ticket

Answer (score 0):

If your string follow fix format and you want to extract value from the string then you can implement a custom function for that something like this.

```
function splitCustom(str){
  var retVal=[];
  str = str.split('.0 index')[1].trim();
  var totalRecord=str[str.lastIndexOf(' index')-1];
  for(var i=0;i<=totalRecord;i++){
    var obj={};
    var substr=str.split("." + (i+1) + ' index');   
    var curRecord="";
    if(substr.length>1){
      curRecord=substr[0].trim();
      str = substr[1].trim();
    }
    else{
      curRecord=str;
    }    
    obj.index=i;
    var labelString=curRecord.split("." + i + ".")[1].trim();
    obj.label=labelString.substr(labelString.indexOf('"')+1, labelString.lastIndexOf('"')-labelString.indexOf('"')-1);
    var valueString=curRecord.split("." + i + ".")[2].trim();
    obj.value=valueString.substr(valueString.indexOf('"')+1, valueString.lastIndexOf('"')-valueString.indexOf('"')-1);
    retVal.push(obj);
  }
  return retVal;
}
var str='.0 index .0.label unicode "Area" .0.value unicode "6WAY DB" .1 index .1.label unicode "SubStation" .1.value unicode "E782DB257"';
var response = splitCustom(str);
```

Output

```
[
    {"index":0,"label":"Area","value":"6WAY DB"},
    {"index":1,"label":"SubStation","value":"E782DB257"}
]
```